# What are all the modifiers in raid mode of Resident Evil: Revelations 2

Tags: resident-evil-revelations-2

What are all the modifiers in the monsters in Raid Mode of Resident Evil: Revelations 2?

Answer (score 1):

Here is picture with all elite icons:
[image]

And what these icons mean:

> 1. **Sprinters** are another common variant of standard enemies that appear a bit smaller and move much faster than their counterparts. Their speed also makes the less likely to flinch and be stunned, but they'll have lower health to compensate.
> 2. **Tanks**. These enemies appear as bigger versions of their counterparts, and have more HP, attack power, and less likely to be stunned by your attacks. This is a very common type of elite enemy, and luckily, their increased strength comes with reduced speed.
> 3. **Flaming Elites**. As their name implies, you can easily recognize these enemies as they are coated in flames from head to toe. This means it will burn anything and everyone it touches, as well as being able to explode on death. With fire based attacks, they'll become weak to ice based attacks, and you will also be immune if using a melee attack to finish them.
> 4. **Frozen Elites**.  Much like the flaming elites, frozen elites can be seen by their solid icy figures. These enemies will freeze anything they come into contact with, and explode upon death in freezing burst. Like the flaming elites weakness to ice, so too to the freezing elites become weak to fire-based weaponry.
> 5. **Shocking Elites**. The shocking elites emit electricity wherever they go and will shock anything they touch, as well as having increased speed like the sprinters.
> 6. **Shield Elites**. The shield elites can be seen by the large force fields they put up in front of themselves. the fields will stop any and all attacks from hitting the elite and any enemies behind him. However, this only spreads to the front of the enemy, allowing you to attack from the sides, behind, or to the legs when possible.
> 7. **Healers** will blend in with other enemies, but can be spotted through the green gas emitted from enemies that they heal, as the elite will constantly heal others near it.
> 8. **Attractors** can be seen by the slowly flashing light that surrounds them, and pulls you in from wherever you stand. There is nothing you can do to stop them from pulling you, save using the environment to keep yourself away.
> 9. **Disarmers** emit a small pulsating field that will disarm the player of their primary weapon. The shockwave comes in bursts, allowing the player to change weapons to something less valuable
> 10. **Countdown Elites**. You can spot Countdown Elites by the large red aura the project around themselves. Upon entering this field, a countdown from 30 seconds will appear. Failure to leave their aura or kill the elite will result in an instant game over.
> 11. **Invisible Elites**. Like Glasps, invisible elites cannot be seen, except by the dust the kick up. You can bring them into view by aiming down your gun sights.
> 12. **Poisonous elites** can be seen from afar by the noxious green gas cloud coming from their feet every so often. If you happen to stray too close to their gas, you will take heavy damage, even if the enemy does not attack you directly.
> 13. **Metal elites** are seen by their coat of steel that encases them, and boast great defense, at the cost of low health. They also grant bonus amounts of XP upon death, and are weak to a follow-up melee attack when they are on the ground.
> 14. **Golden elites** are much like the metal elites, trading a steel coat for golden skin. They share the same high defense as the metal elites, and grand additional gold as well as XP upon defeat.
> 15. **Buffers** also blend in with other enemies, but you can spot an enemy  that they have buffed by the pink outlines that they give benefits to. They will grant random abilities to those among them, making them a viable threat.

[Source](http://www.ign.com/wikis/resident-evil-revelations-2/Raid_Mode).